# How do I check if an array element exists?

Tags: java

I'm looking for Java's equivalent of PHP's [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php);

```
int board[][]=new int[8][8];
...
if(isset(board[y][x]))
  // Do something with board[y][x]
```

Does such a function exist in Java?

Edit: Sorry, what I meant is that I want to check if `board[100][100]` exists or not. `if(board[100][100])` would result in an array out of bounds error.

Comment: What is the function of `isset()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, `int` arrays are initialized to a value of zero, so you won't be able to tell if it's been not set, or if it's set to a value of 0.

If you want to check if it's set, you should use an array of `Integer`. If the value isn't set, it will be `null`.

```
Integer[][] board = new Integer[8][8];
...
if (board[x][y] != null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a basic null check would work.

```
String[] myArray = {"Item1", "Item2"};

for(int x =0; x < myArray.length; x++){
    if(myArray[0] != null)
    {
      ...do something
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be if(myArray[x] != null)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method that checks that first the x, y is in the bounds of the array and if it is that the value is not null. I don't believe there is a built in method for array, but there are helper functions similar like .contains() for ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to not use int, you could use Integer if you really have to have it as an int, but generally speaking a complex object is going to be better (like a ChessPiece or something).  That way you can check to see if the value == null (null means it has not been set).

Answer (score -1):

```
  if (board[x][y] != null) {
    // it's not null, but that doesn't mean it's "set" either.  You may want to do further checking to ensure the object or primitive data here is valid
  }
```

Java doesn't have an equiv. to isset because knowing if something is truly set goes beyond just stuffing a value into a location.

Comment: Ack... don't catch that exception!

Comment: Just wondering...why? I am all for less exception handling and more coding

Comment: http://books.google.ca/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&redir_esc=y (chapter 9, item 57).  Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions.  There is nothing exceptional about going out of bounds.  Also exception handling is usually the slower path through the code (not optimized by the VM) so it can be an unnecessary a performance issue.  FInally it is a RuntimeException which indicates a programmers mistake - fix the bug don't work around it.  Add the if checks for x/y being in range, it is faster, clearer, and less error prone.

Comment: Nice, always good to know.  :)  I prefer less exception handling, but come from a background where our previous project was basically try { // too damn much business logic } catch (every exception under the sun) {} no excuses.  Always appreciate a learning session! :)